# Can I overide a member of an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm not sure if I'm wording this question right, so I'll just start with some code. This isn't from my program, but hopefully its enough to get the concept across.

```
class AbstractClass {

public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass> Ptr;
    std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;
    void AddChild(Ptr child);
    void Render();
}


class Derived {

public:
typedef std::unique_ptr<Derived> Ptr;
std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;

private:
void CheckChildren();
}
```

As you can see, I'm essentially "overriding" the abstract class's "mChildren". This works fine for my Render() method which uses mChildren to recursively render all children. However, when I try to call CheckChildren() from the derived class, mChildren shows up as empty.

This is after calling the

```
AddChild(std::move(new Derived));
```

method too. The thing is, my Render method works fine, meaning that mChildren is not empty. It appears that I am unable to see the collection correctly from my derived class. I'm sure this is probably mostly a problem with not encapsulating the children correctly, but I'm stumped on how to resolve this problem.

Would keeping mChildren as a private member help? I just tried letting mChildren be private and creating a getter that returned a pointer to the vector, but VS wouldn't allow  my derived class's getter to return a pointer to a vector of derived classes.

To summarize - I need to be able to access the collection as it was all AbstractClass::Ptr's, yet I need to be able to modify the Derived::Ptr as a Derived object with more methods.

Comment: If your intention is to just use one m_Children then remove 'std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;' from derived class. (Also your class is not actually derived)

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code - I cannot go into all of them (no time now) -but:

```
class Derived {

public:
....
std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;
```

That is not an "override" - you have **REDECLARED** mChildren - it's a different instance than the one in your "abstract class" (it's not really abstract, but that's a different story) - so when you call it from the base class, you'll get the member from the base class, but when you call it from the derived class you'll get a DIFFERENT member - the one from the derived class.

Also - I'm not sure exactly how you are using this code but your derived class here is not derived - it's a different class entirely:

try this:

```
class AbstractClass {

  public:

    typedef std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass> Ptr;
    void AddChild(Ptr child)

  protected:
   std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;

...

}

class Derived: public AbstractClass{...
```

**Do not redeclare mChildren in the derived class.** When you declare it as protected in the base class, it  'lives' in the base class but the same member is accessible from the derived class. That should fix your problem.

But you need to read up on access modifiers, abstract methods, virtual methods and inheritance. Any decent C++ book or online tutorial will get you up and running with that stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I typed this code out and didn't copy it from my program. My derived class does inherit from my abstract base class. My problem is that my base class doesn't support all of the methods that I need by derived class to support. The derived class should contain members that *are* DerivedClasses, but should also be able to do the basic functions that are in my base class. This is the dilemma.

For example: Imagine a Bodypart base class. Bone,Wrist, and Head all need to Render(). However, Bones can have child Bodyparts, Wrist can have Bones, etc..

Comment: @user1781726 - then you declare render() in the base virtual and do what is common to all class there, then override it in the derived classes to do additional stuff. See [Polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) - for a complete tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override data members in C++, only virtual functions.

Comment: +1 True. I didn't mention it because I figured the OP just meant using the member from the base class in the derived class. As I mentioned, and as I'm sure you know, just about all the code in the question is wrong.